# how to toggle setState value?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

this code only shows More text, there is no less button working.

how to toggle false and true for '...more' and '...less' buttons?

```
<Text style={styles.headerText}>Roller skating in the park</Text>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <Text style={styles.comments}>
          {isMore
            ? 'It was an amazing time with people! Hope'
            : 'It was an amazing time with people! Hope It was an amazing time with people! Hope It was an amazing time with people! Hope It was an amazing time with people! Hope It was an amazing time with people! Hope'}
          !
        </Text>
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Pressable
            onPress={() => {
              setisMore(false);
            }}
            disabled={!isMore}>
            <Text>{isMore ? '...more' : '...less'}</Text>
          </Pressable>
        </View>
      </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `!` operator to define a toggling state.

For example, if you have:

```js
const [isMore, setIsMore] = useState(false)
```

You can toggle between `true` and `false` values by triggering

```js
setIsMore(!isMore)
```

What it does is it takes the value of `isMore` and negates it, then sets it as the default value. So if your `isMore` was `false` at first, after using

```js
setIsMore(!isMore)
```

it will become `true` and vice versa.

Also, you should remove the `disabled={!isMore}` for your input.
This is because you want the **'...more'** button to always be clickable. You should use `disabled` only when you want to disable the input when a certain variable is true. So you would use it in say a form where you can only input the username if you select a 'Set Username' option.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably set `isMore` to the negated value. So if `isMore` is `false`, you would want to update it to `true`:

```
<Pressable
  onPress={() => {
    setisMore(!isMore);
  }}
  disabled={!isMore}> //why do you disable the Pressable? shouldn't it be able to toggle?
  <Text>{isMore ? '...more' : '...less'}</Text>
</Pressable>
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed with this:

```
  const toggle = () => setisMore(value => !value);
```